# Obtain the name of the folders and the link of the file contained in it from the parent folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I have some movies arranged as follows.

MOVIES / spider man (2020) /spiderman-2020-sd-eng.mp4

I want the following information to be extracted in a spreadsheet.

| **name** | **link** |
| --- | --- |
| spider man (2020) | link movie mp4 |

Where:
**spider man (2020)**: is the name of the folder where the movie is located
**mp4 movie link**: it's the spiderman-2020-sd-eng.mp4 movie link

The code that I have extracts the name of the *folder*, but it also extracts the *link* of the folder ... (I would like it to extract the name of the folder and the link of the movie).

result of the code I have:

```
// replace your-folder below with the folder for which you want a listing
function listFolderContents() {

  var foldersID = DriveApp.getFolderById("10Zw76wu2UNz3jufimUFGd8OJErPGnsih");
  var foldername = foldersID.getName();
  var folderlisting = 'listado de ' + foldername;
  
  var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(foldername)
  var folder = folders.next();
  var contents = folder.getFolders();

  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.create(folderlisting);
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.appendRow( ['name','link'] );
  var file;
  var name;
  var link;
  while(contents.hasNext()) {
    file = contents.next();
    name = file.getName();
    link = file.getUrl();
    sheet.appendRow( [name, link] );     
  }  
};
```

Can you help me...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You are getting the same folder `MOVIE` twice (`foldersID`, `folders`)
2. You are not iterating the sub-folders under `MOVIE`
3. You are not getting and iterating the `files` under the sub-folders

```js
function listFolderContents() {
  var foldersID = DriveApp.getFolderById("10Zw76wu2UNz3jufimUFGd8OJErPGnsih");
  var foldername = foldersID.getName();
  var folderlisting = 'listado de ' + foldername;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.create(folderlisting);
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.appendRow( ['name','link'] );
  
  var folders = foldersID.getFolders();
  while (folders.hasNext()) {
    var folder = folders.next();
    var name = folder.getName();

    var files = folder.getFiles();
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      var file = files.next();
      var link = file.getUrl();
      sheet.appendRow([name, link]);
    }
  }
}
```